# Android: Set SMS Notification Tone

Tags: android, sms, notifications

I need to change the SMS notification tone using code in android. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: What's the question?  This is just a statement.

Comment: let me get my magic wand and get that working for you

Comment: Not a great question, but I think the intent is clear - Vivek wants to change the sound that plays on incoming text messages, which I believe is not possible since that's a proprietary setting inside the SMS messaging app (which varies from phone to phone).

Comment: I am developing a sound board application and I need the code to change the notification tone to the one in my res/raw folder..

Comment: ChompSMS has the ability to set ringtone, so it definitely seems possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you should use RingtoneManager class:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  MainActivity.this,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
  newUri
);
```

I lifted the code from here: [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029876/setting-ringtone-notification-from-sd-card-file).

Comment: @Vivek: you need to be more descriptive. Help us help you, ya know?

Comment: That's the generic notification sound. However, the standard Android messaging app has the option to set any arbitrary ringtone. I haven't looked at the source code yet - does it just overwrite TYPE_NOTIFICATION, or does it have its own setting in its SharedPreferences?