# setting audio file as Ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

I have save file in `sdcard/media/audio/ringtone`s folder. That file will appear in list of ringtone selection from `settings/sound/phone` Ringtone.

But I want to set that file as a ringtone from my code.
Here is my code.

```
  File k = new File(path, filename);

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "TwiAppclip");
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

  Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
       .getAbsolutePath());
  Uri newUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

  RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),
      RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```

here `uri` I am getting But I got `newUri = null`. I think that's why its is not setting as ringtone.

Anyone know where is the problem? how do I get `newUri` proper?

Comment: if I put my ringtones on raw folder, what should I specify as PATH? :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Audio is set as ringtone only once, but solution to this problem is - If you are trying to run the same code again, you'll be inserting a duplicate entry into MediaStore's table, but the SQLite database won't allow you. You have to either rename your file and add another instance of it, or go in, remove the entry, and then try again. So I removed that entry every time and then insert it again.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(activity.this,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks, I've been searching all over for the syntax on how to properly query for a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks man. That was great. I was looking for this for weeks and u know what. The catch block catches this exception but exception variable is null. I had no clue it could be this issue. Thanks :D

Comment: -1 for this answer as it does not work! Lack of checking for delete, so this code surrounding getting the Uri and doing the delete is lazy code! The more correct answer would have been to obtain the media's _ID and this int nRowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_UR‌​I + "/" + _ID), null, null); if (nRowsDeleted > 0){ // delete worked }else{ // delete failed }

Comment: Could not help noticing btw the similarity in the answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029876/setting-ringtone-notification-from-sd-card-file/4613172#4613172... just saying :)

Comment: both are same answers as i give answer which you give link.

Comment: @djk could you help me? I am also getting insert uri as null only on specific device

Comment: gives me an error by android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS missing

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting the previously inserted uri, you can reuse it:

```
    // check if file already exists in MediaStore
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
    String selectionClause = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = {ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath()};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selectionClause, selectionArgs, null);
    Uri insertedUri;
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        // not exist, insert into MediaStore
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        cv.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, ringtoneFile.getName());
        insertedUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
    } else {
        // already exist
        cursor.moveToNext();
        long id = cursor.getLong(0);
        insertedUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    }
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, insertedUri);
```

Comment: Was this meant to "replace" the previous ringtone?

Answer (score 1):

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
Context,
RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
Uri
.parse("Media file uri"));
```

I think this will solve ur problem.

Comment: I don't think you got the question.