# How to clear Mediastore before setting ringtone

Tags: java, android, ringtone, mediastore

When I set a ringtone from my app works once, but when running the code again, it tries to create a duplicate entry in the media store, which creates problems. Without creating seperate unique file names for every sound file, I want to fix this problem.

I found this solution posted in an answer here: [setting audio file as Ringtone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603941/problem-in-setting-audio-file-as-ringtone) 
and am trying to use that to fix mine.

When I try it in my code below, I get two errors. One is an SQLiteException and the other is a RuntimeException which is caused by the squlite error, which is after the Java code.

```
String TAG = "CFFS";


    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/ringtones"); // Set base DIR where new ringtone will live
    dir.mkdirs(); // create if directors don't exist

    File outputFile = new File(dir, "College Fight Song.mp3"); // Define out new output file


    Uri inURI = null;
    try {
        inURI = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("com.carboni.fightsongs.FILE_RES_ID"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get URI " + e);
    }


    // If we didn't parse a good URI then don't execute the code below
    if (inURI != null) {
        InputStream in = null;
        // Get the input stream
        try { in = new BufferedInputStream(this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(inURI));           }
        catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, "Exception getting input stream " + e); }

        // Get the output stream
        OutputStream out = null;
        try { out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); } 
        catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, "Exception getting output stream " + e); }

        // Again, if we don't have 2 good handles then don't try to read/write them
        if ((in != null) && (out != null)) {

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; // Define our buffer size
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while (bytesRead >= 0) {
                try {
                    bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length); // Read max of 1024 bytes
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                        out.write(buf); // Write buffer to new file if we got a good read
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Exception reading " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
        }
        // Close out handles and proceed
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, "Exception closing streams " + e); }

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        v.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "College Football Fight Song");
        v.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, outputFile.length());
        v.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        v.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);

        Uri pURI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // remove entry every time so we don't get duplicate entries and have a problem setting a 2nd time
        getContentResolver().delete(pURI, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "\"" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

        Uri nURI = this.getContentResolver().insert(pURI, v);

        Log.i(TAG, "Setting ringtone URI to " + nURI);

        // Set ringtone
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, nURI);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ringtone set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

ERROR:

```
09-03 14:16:08.343: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(11968): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ""/mnt/sdcard/ringtones/College Fight Song.mp3"": syntax error: , while compiling: DELETE FROM audio_meta WHERE _data"/mnt/sdcard/ringtones/College Fight Song.mp3"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the error is this line:

```
getContentResolver().delete(pURI, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "\"" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + "=\"", null);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the quoted value?

Comment: Use DATA + "=\"" instead of DATA + "\"". You can see in the Sql error that you have WHERE _data"..." instead of WHERE _data="...".