# Android Studio Alarm Clock MP3 Song

Tags: java, android, mp3, alarm

I'm making an alarm clock. I have the codes below. However, the notification music is working. I want it to play the mp3 file I set. What should I do?

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null)
        {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();
    }
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603941/setting-audio-file-as-ringtone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code :

```
   Uri alarmUri  = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
   if (alarmUri == null)
    {
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
       mp.start();
    }
```

Please used below code when you get notification in BroadcastReceiver then call activity in that activity class used below code so play sound file.

```
 mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); 
 mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Where do I write "song.mp3"? My goal is to play song.mp3 on alarm.

Comment: @haresh mb you provide the answer, but simply saying `try X` isn't helpful for others. What's more, your answer uses the `notification` variable, which is not described in the context of question. How should I define that variable/parameter, cause now it gives the syntax error.

Comment: @itwasntme sorry but i am not getting you?

Comment: I mean, using the variables (also their names) that wasn't used in question makes it difficult to reuse by others. So calling the `MediaPlayer.create(.....)` with `notification` is hard to determinate by others, same goes to `R.raw.sound1` - it's not shown/used anywhere else, I know I'd need to declare/put it in resources, but for some1 unfaimilliar it forwards to another problem.

Comment: I not understand ```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Uri alarmUri  = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (alarmUri == null)
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), notification);
            mp.start();
        }
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Comment: is my answer was helpful then please upvote and accept and if you are still stuck please let me know